# Parsing "Freilich verstanden sie sich auf ihre Weise darauf ..."

Tags: grammar, german-to-english

I'm trying to understand the following sentence:

> Freilich verstanden sie sich auf ihre Weise darauf, so wie Blutegel sich aufs Blut verstehen, und auf ihre Weise handelten sie danach

I understand bits of it -- my best attempt is

> Of course they were experts in its way, just as leeches are experts in blood, and they acted

But a literal translation would really help me out. In particular, I don't understand the role of 'darauf' and 'danach' in the sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rough understanding of the sentence (which is an admittedly obscure one -- where did you find this? I'm curious :) ) goes in the right direction.

The translation would go something like

> Naturally they knew all about it* in their own way, just like leeches know all about blood, and acted on it [=their understanding/knowledge]

*) the object of the first main clause is not mentioned in this excerpt; it is to be taken from the context and was probably mentioned in one of the previous sentences

As for the roles of "darauf" and "danach" in this case: they are both part of the phrasal verbs "[sich auf etw. verstehen](http://dict.leo.org/ende/?lp=ende&lang=en&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=sich%20auf%20etw%20verstehen)" and "[nach etw. handeln](http://dict.leo.org/ende/?lp=ende&lang=en&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=nach%20etw%20handeln)" where the noun or pronoun of the object (marked by "etw[as]" in the dictionary forms) gets pulled into the proposition, turning "auf" into "*dar*auf" and "nach" into "*da*nach".

Comment: This is very helpful! It's from 'Momo' by Michael Ende

Answer (score 7):

Literal translation:

> Freilich = naturally, of course
>
> sich auf etwas verstehen = to be an expert in sth / to know well about sth
>
> sie = they
>
> darauf = cannot be translated literally in general. It's a concoction of the preposition `auf` and the pronoun `es`/`das`. As the preposition is part of the verb, the literal translation depends on the translation of the verb. The pronoun would be translated as `it` or even left out.
>
> auf ihre Weise = in their own way
>
> so wie = just like / like / as
>
> Blut = blood
>
> und = and
>
> handeln = to act
>
> danach = accordingly

Comment: It was the 'auf ihre Weise' that was throwing me off - now that you've explained that it all clicked into place. Thanks!